# What's the difference between OrderedList and SortedList

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

[`Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Modifiers.html) provides both `OrderedList` and `SortedList`.

The documentation for `SortedList` says:

> `Sorted xs`: guarantees that `xs` is sorted.

The documentation for `OrderedList` says:

> `Ordered xs`: guarantees that `xs` is ordered.

(I'm guessing those should say `SortedList xs` and `OrderedList xs` respectively).

What is the difference between a list that is ordered and a list that is sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: I think `OrderedList` should be deprecated, and its `shrink` implementation ported to `SortedList`.

They are both defined as

```
newtype FooList a = Foo { getFoo :: [a] }
```

but with different choices of `Foo`. (As an aside: this explains why the documentation says `Sorted xs` and `Ordered xs` not `SortedList xs` and `OrderedList xs` -- these are computation-level terms, not type-level ones, so the documentation is correct!)

There are no special helper functions available other than instances, so if there is a difference it must be in the instances. Both derive `(Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Typeable)`, so no difference there.

`OrderedList` has a `Functor` instance while `SortedList` doesn't, but I think `OrderedList` shouldn't have one either: its `fmap` does not preserve the invariant promised by the documentation of being ordered. This fact is my desiderata for whether to deprecate `SortedList` or `OrderedList`: deprecate the one with the bad `Functor` instance, so that you have just one backwards-incompatible change of removing a type, rather than deprecating one and removing a bad `Functor` instance from the other.

The `Arbitrary` instances are nearly identical:

```
instance (Ord a, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (OrderedList a) where
  arbitrary = Ordered `fmap` orderedList

  shrink (Ordered xs) =
    [ Ordered xs'
    | xs' <- shrink xs
    , sort xs' == xs'
    ]

orderedList :: (Ord a, Arbitrary a) => Gen [a]
orderedList = sort `fmap` arbitrary

instance (Arbitrary a, Ord a) => Arbitrary (SortedList a) where
  arbitrary = fmap (Sorted . sort) arbitrary

  shrink (Sorted xs) =
    [ Sorted xs'
    | xs' <- map sort (shrink xs)
    ]
```

So the only difference in behavior is that `OrderedList` does an equality check while `SortedList` doesn't. This means that the `SortedList` instance does less work inside `shrink` but produces more duplicate elements. The `OrderedList` choice is a better tradeoff if an equality check is cheaper than checking the property you are currently trying to find a minimal case for; that seems likely to be the case in most situations to me.

(One can almost certainly produce a more efficient `shrink` implementation than either of these.)